# Why isn't sudo authentication in one terminal propagated to another terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, security, sudo

When I `sudo` followed by a password in one terminal and then sudo in another terminal, I have to enter my password again. I am pretty sure it wasn't always like this. If I recall correctly, you could `sudo` in one terminal and then execute a `sudo` in a different terminal without having to enter the password, as long as the second sudo took place within 5 minutes of the first.

How can I restore this old behavior in recent versions of macOS?

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior described by the OP occurs with OS X El Capitan and previous versions of OS X. This is where a single record in the time stamp file is used for all login sessions. (This behavior contradicts what is posted in `man sudoers` for OS X El Capitan.) The current default behavior, where there is a separate record in the time stamp file for each terminal, began with macOS Sierra and continues through macOS Ventura.

After some testing with previous versions of OS X/macOS, I can confirm [Allan's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/680982) is correct. The relevant part of this comment is repeated below.

> Try adding this line (using `visudo`) to the `/etc/sudoers` file: `Defaults !tty_tickets`.

Note that starting with macOS High Sierra, `Defaults !tty_tickets` has been superseded by `Defaults timestamp_type = "global"`. In other words, both make the same change. You can see the change by entering `sudo sudo -V | grep 'timestamp record'`.

Comment: Are there some security or "best practices (e.g., mistakes like `sudo rm -rf /`)" implications that motivates this change?

Comment: It's a risky practice to keep many terminals where you are root. Imagine the potential damages of an accidental paste. Thus, Apple, as usual, decided to protect the weakests against their own errors. My personnal practice is to switch to black the color of my terminal before switching to root. When I have this kind of terminal I know any remote access should be blocked.